# resend docusign event notification

Tags: docusignapi

What happens when the event notification is triggered from docusign and our server is down or due to network issue we didn't receive the notification. Will the docusign sends it again or we need to do the pooling.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please accept and [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answer if it addressed your question. Please comment if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your *requiresAcknowledgement* configuration of Connect

---

**requiresAcknowledgement**

> *When set to true, and a publication message fails to be acknowledged, the message goes back into the queue and the system will retry
>   delivery after a successful acknowledgement is received. If the
>   delivery fails a second time, the message is not returned to the queue
>   for sending until Connect receives a successful acknowledgement and it
>   has been at least 24 hours since the previous retry. There is a
>   maximum of ten retries Alternately, you can use Republish  Connect
>   Information to manually republish the envelope information.*

API Docs Source: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectConfigurations/get/

Comment: Some additional details: the first re-send will only occur after 24 hours since the prior attempt and a new notification is sent via the same subscription (configuration). If Send Individual Messages is activated then the re-sends will occur regardless of a new notification being sent. I'm in the process of updating the docs.